# Regex isn't recognized in a curl/grep combination

Tags: regex, windows, curl, sed, grep

I try to get image urls from a list of html urls with following curl/grep/seed combination (with `wget` I fail with 403, but `cUrl` get the source code correctly):

```
curl -K "C:\urls.txt" | "C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -o '(http[^\s]+(jpg|png|webp)\b)' | sed 's/\?.*//' > imglinks.txt
```

But I get an error `The command "png" is either misspelled or could not be found.`

Regex should be correct: https://regex101.com/r/Qk6A0Z/1/

How could this code be improved?

**Edit**: the source code of a single url from my list one can see running `curl https://watchbase.com/sellita`

The snippet, from where I want to get image urls looks like

```
<picture>
<source type="image/webp" data-srcset="https://cdn.watchbase.com/caliber/md/origin:png/sellita/sw200-1-bd.webp" srcset="https://assets.watchbase.com/img/FFFFFF-0.png" />
<img class="lazyload" data-src="https://cdn.watchbase.com/caliber/md/sellita/sw200-1-bd.png" src="https://assets.watchbase.com/img/FFFFFF-0.png" alt="Sellita caliber SW200-1"/>
</picture>
```

Expected output is a file with all image urls, even those from `data-src` and `data-srcset`.

Comment: You are doing something very wrong, why use `curl -K 'C:\urls.txt' | grep -o pattern`? You can simply use `"C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -oP "http[^?\s]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" "C:\urls.txt" > imglinks.txt`

Comment: On this way I get only empty file imglinks.txt. If I use instead of file list a single url, like `"C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -oP "http[^?\s]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" https://watchbase.com/sellita > imglinks.txt` I get `no such file or directory`

Comment: Can you show output of your `curl` command and also show your expected final output.

Comment: Just tried, and `"C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -oE "http[^?[:space:]]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" "C:\urls.txt"` works well. Same as `"C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -oP "http[^?\s]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" "C:\urls.txt"`

Comment: At any rate, the `'png' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` issue is due to the use of single quotation marks. Use double.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this `xargs+curl+grep` pipeline:

```sh
xargs -n 1 curl < "C:\urls.txt" | "C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -Eo "http[^[:blank:]?'\"]+(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|ico|tiff|webp)\b" > imglinks.txt
```

Comment: This line worked `xargs curl < "C:\urls.txt" | "C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -Eo "http[^?[:space:]]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" > imglinks.txt`, but there were only 10 urls processed from 33.000 urls, contained in the file `urls.txt`.

Comment: sure, I have. From here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm

Comment: Both failed:

`C:\GnuWin32\bin>sed 's/\r//$' "C:\urls.txt" | xargs curl | "C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -Eo "http[^?[:space:]]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" > imglinks.txt
sed: -e Ausdruck #1, Zeichen 1: Unbekannter Befehl: \`''
curl: try "curl --help" for more information`

`C:\GnuWin32\bin>sed "s/\r//$" "C:\urls.txt" | xargs curl | "C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -Eo "http[^?[:space:]]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" > imglinks.txt
sed: -e Ausdruck #1, Zeichen 7: Unbekannte Option fcurl: try "curl --help" for more information`

Comment: `C:\GnuWin32\bin>curl -n 1 < "C:\urls.txt" | "C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -Eo "http[^?[:space:]]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" > imglinks.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 1`

Comment: Try this one: `xargs -n 1 curl < "C:\urls.txt" | "C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -Eo "http[^?[:space:]]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" > imglinks.txt`

Comment: It began to work and worked longer then previously - but stopped after around 100 urls :( :( :( oh my bad luck...

Comment: It should work by running one URL at a time. May be there is some resource issue on your Windows machine.

Comment: to be exact, it stopped after 82 urls. While running something like `wget.exe -i imagelist.txt` there were no any issues with it.

Comment: You can try to replace `curl` with `wget`

Comment: using `wget` I get 403 :(

Comment: So if you get 403 with `wget` then how come there are no issues with `wget -i`?

Comment: Anyway there is no restriction with `xargs` command to stop after 82 or 100 unless there are some external restrictions on that system. I have used `xargs` to process millions of lines.

Comment: I was doing `wget` accessing image urls directly. It seems the website prevents direct access to html pages with `wget` - but `cUrl` can access them.

Comment: `while` doesn't work on my WIndows. I tested `xargs -n 1 curl < "C:\urls.txt" | "C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -Eo "http[^?[:space:]]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" > imglinks.txt` on another machine in another network - it stopped again after exactly 82 urls.

Comment: Test it on a non-windows machine if you can

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
curl "https://watchbase.com/sellita"  | "C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -oE "http[^?[:space:]]+(jpg|png|webp)\b"  > imglinks.txt
```

The `'png' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` issue is due to the use of single quotation marks. You should use double quotation marks in Windows `grep`.

To read all URLs from a file and process them, you may use

```
FOR /F %i in (C:\urls.txt) DO curl %i | "C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -oP "http[^?\s]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" >> imglinks.txt
```

Comment: Yes, it works indeed! Is there a possibility to use a file with an url list instead of single url? I tried `curl "C:\urls.txt"` with and without `-K` - but no luck with both...

Comment: @Evgeniy I have already shared that: `"C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -oE "http[^?[:space:]]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" "C:\urls.txt" > imglinks.txt`. You should pass the file path to `grep` directly.

Comment: on this way I get only empty `imglinks.txt`

Comment: @Evgeniy What is inside `"C:\urls.txt"`? The text where the URLs to extract are? Or a list of Web pages that you need to scape?

Comment: urls like in your answer, separated with `\r\n`

Comment: @Evgeniy You can read a file line by line using `FOR /F %i in (C:\urls.txt) DO your_command`

Comment: @Evgeniy So, did you try this in the `cmd`? Or, are you running it from a batch file?

Comment: I still struggle with syntax, can't get it run from cmd

Comment: @Evgeniy See [this demo screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/21FCqiR), it works fine.

Comment: For a single URL I've already managed it out. Now my last problem is - to read urls from a txt file and to save image urls into another txt file.

Comment: @Evgeniy Ok, so that means the current question is answered, right? Now, you want to save the URLs you extract from certain Web pages into separate TXT files, don't you? Sorry, it is not clear what your problem is, I already posted how to read a TXT file line by line and extract the pattern matches into a TXT file.

Comment: hmm, my initial question is about reading urls from txt file and writing image urls into another txt file. The problem hasn't changed while discussion. Do you have another sight on it?

Comment: @Evgeniy "into another txt file" - this is already solved. `FOR /F %i in (C:\1\1.txt) DO ("c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl.exe" %i | "c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -oP "http[^?\s]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" >> imglinks.txt)` (that I execute on my end) writes all the links found on the Web pages (listed in the `C:\1\1.txt` file) in the `imglinks.txt` file.

Comment: After pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> with `FOR /F %i in (C:\urls.txt) DO ("C:\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" %i | "c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -oP "http[^?\s]+(jpg|png|webp)\b" >> imglinks.txt` I get just `more?` It looks like on screenshot: https://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1473/9830351270.png

Comment: @Evgeniy You are passing the `urls.txt` to grep, why? You say you have URLs there, so pass the `urls.txt` to **curl**.

Answer (score 0):

It's really bad practice trying to parse HTML with RegEX! And to see senior members even encouraging this really makes me want to cry. This way the constant flood of these questions will never end.

Please have a look at:

- [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105)
- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348)

To parse HTML please use an HTML parser like [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint), [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet), or [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel)!

> ```
> <picture>
> <source type="image/webp" data-srcset="https://cdn.watchbase.com/caliber/md/origin:png/sellita/sw200-1-bd.webp" srcset="https://assets.watchbase.com/img/FFFFFF-0.png" />
> <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://cdn.watchbase.com/caliber/md/sellita/sw200-1-bd.png" src="https://assets.watchbase.com/img/FFFFFF-0.png" alt="Sellita caliber SW200-1"/>
> </picture>
> ```

https://assets.watchbase.com/img/FFFFFF-0.png is just 1 white pixel and returns in every single `<picture>`-node. So I'm going to assume you just want the attributes `data-srcset` and `data-src`.

```
xidel -s "https://watchbase.com/sellita" -e "//picture/(source/@data-srcset,img/@data-src)"
```

You can also use `xidel` (with just 1 invocation) to process the urls you have in `"C:\urls.txt"` (assuming they all have the same `<picture>`-nodes as https://watchbase.com/sellita).

```
xidel -s "C:\urls.txt" -e "for $url in x:lines($raw) return doc($url)//picture/(source/@data-srcset,img/@data-src)" > imglinks.txt
```

or

```
xidel -se "for $url in file:read-text-lines('C:\urls.txt') return doc($url)//picture/(source/@data-srcset,img/@data-src)" > imglinks.txt
```

If you're goal is to download all images from *'imglinks.txt'*, then `xidel` can do this too.

```
xidel -s "C:\urls.txt" -f "for $url in x:lines($raw) return doc($url)//picture/(source/@data-srcset,img/@data-src)" --download "."
```

or

```
xidel -s --xquery "for $url in file:read-text-lines('C:\urls.txt') for $img in doc($url)//picture/(source/@data-srcset,img/@data-src) return file:write-binary(tokenize($img,'/')[last()],string-to-base64Binary(x:request($img)/raw))"

xidel -s --xquery ^"^
  for $url in file:read-text-lines('C:\urls.txt')^
  for $img in doc($url)//picture/(source/@data-srcset,img/@data-src)^
  return^
  file:write-binary(^
    tokenize($img,'/')[last()],^
    string-to-base64Binary(x:request($img)/raw)^
  )^
"
```